# Cucumber scenarios with multiple browsers

Tags: cucumber

i'm currently trying to automate browsers tests and am hitting an issue while trying to implement multiple browsers into one feature file

```
Feature: feature X

  Background:
    Given User on X using "Chrome"

  Scenario: X process in Chrome
    when x is 
    then x etc..


  Given User X using "Firefox"
  @Firefox
  Scenario: X process in Firefox
    steps...etc


  Given User on X using "IE"
  @IE
  Scenario: X process in IE
    steps..etc
```

These tests all run fine without being in the same feature file, but I don't know how to separate them, they are all running off the first Given(Chrome)

Thanks

```
Feature: X

  @Chrome
  Scenario: X process in Chrome
    Given User on X using "Chrome"


  @Firefox
  Scenario: X process in Firefox
    Given User on X using "Firefox"


  @IE
  Scenario: X process in IE
    Given User on X using "IE"
```

Comment: Why do you have the step User on X using "IE" (similar for Chrome & Firefox) outside their respective scenarios? They are all running off Chrome because the Chrome Given step is in background step, which will run for all scenarios in the feature file.

Comment: Hi Grasshopper, i've now changed it to have the given inside the scenarios and removed the background, howevers now it is just doing the tests in firefox

Comment: Do you have a tag filter for@Firefox when you are running the test? What does the console say about the number of scenarios run?

Comment: It is running 18 tests(6 x 3), it is seemingly pointing to firefox and IE for the second and third test, the tags 
tags={"@Firefox,@Chrome,@IE"},

Comment: However it just reopns Chrome again, i've placed them into 3 separate feature files and attempt to run them all at once, but the first one to run remains the browser that is used for all scenarios

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)

Comment: First errors from console

Comment: You have a problem in the step definition code... Does it work when you test them independently, ie run only for one browser type?

Comment: It does yes, if they are run separately the run fine

Comment: Can you figure out where the stacktrace is originating from in your step definition code? How are you creating and closing the different browser instances?

Answer (score 1):

The way to run features on different browsers is to have a separate test run for each browser. What your features should be talking about is features not the browser you are running.

So lets say your feature is called 'registration' you would run

```
cucumber features/registration.feature -t @chrome
cucumber features/registration.feature -t @ie
cucumber features/registration.feature -t @firefox
```

You can find out about this by running `cucumber --help`. You can also look at profiles. It is quite difficult (and not recommended) to change the browser in a single test run. Switching browsers takes quite alot of time so you really don't want to do this in a single run.